# How to use MySQL on Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, magento2.4.2

I try to use Elasticsearch, But it doesn't work stability(Elasticsearch die a lot time). How can I use MySQL on Magento 2.4.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Magento 2.4.0, all search functionalities are now using Elasticsearch as search engine:

> Elasticsearch 7.6.x support. Elasticsearch 7.6.x is now the default
> catalog search engine for Magento Commerce and Open Source. You cannot
> install or upgrade to Magento 2.4.0 without also installing
> Elasticsearch 7.6.x.
>
> Removal of the MySQL catalog search engine. The MySQL search engine
> has been removed from Magento 2.4.0 and replaced as the default search
> engine with Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch provides superior search
> capabilities as well as catalog performance optimizations. All
> merchants must have Elasticsearch to install and deploy Magento 2.4.0.

(Reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-open-source.html#platform-upgrades)

With Magento OOTB latest versions, there is no way to go back into using MySQL as search engine. So your solution will be to seek for a 3rd party module or create your own customizations which is going to be a difficult task to cover all new updates and upgrades from now on also.

Comment: It's help. Thank you!

Comment: You're most welcome!